# Difficulty opening port 5432 for PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to get a postgres database talking to a django installation.

I've followed the steps details here: http://blog.iiilx.com/programming/how-to-install-postgres-on-ubuntu-for-django/

However, when I use syncdb to have django update my postgres database, I receive the following error:

```
connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "/home/flowcore/django_db" 
does not exist
```

django_db is the name of the database and it DOES exist but of course it doesn't exist at /home/flowcore/django_db (that is not where postgres stores data!)

My databases dict in settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_db'),
        'USER': 'django_login',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypasswordhere',  #obviously i've replaced this with my actual password
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

Do I have to specific an absolute path to my postgres database file and, if so, where are these files stored?

Comment: You should show the DATABASES dict in settings.py.

Comment: You don't need a path. Just the name. ("django_db", I presume)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done, i've added it to the original question :)

Comment: @wildplasser I've just added my setting.py above - you can see it already points to that.

Comment: No, there is an `os.path.join()` on that line. (don't know what that is supposed to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for some reason you have put the full path as the `NAME` parameter, so it's not surprising that Django is using that. There's no reason to do that, and that tutorial you link to doesn't suggest it. `NAME` is the database name itself, which as you say is just "django_db".

Comment: A silly mistake on my part. I didn't even think through what os.path.join() was doing! Thanks!